# Using powershell from a batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-10

I want to take advantage of `powershell` to make some simple math calculations inside a batch script. I'm able to calculate a floating point division in a batch script with

```
set numerator=3.5
for /f %%i in ('powershell 10/%numerator%') do (set result=%%i)
```

which correctly sets the `result` variable to `2.85714285714286`, but I was not able to call from the batch script a powershell command like `powershell [math]::max(3,4)`, which returns the maximum of two numbers. Calling

```
for /f %%i in ('powershell [math]::max^(3,4^)') do (set result=%%i)
```

from a batch script sets the `result` variable to `+`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `,` needs to be escaped as well. Otherwise, you get the powershell error

> At line:1 char:14
>   + [math]::max(3 4)
>   +              ~
>   Missing ')' in method call.
>   At line:1 char:15
>   + [math]::max(3 4)
>   +               ~
>   Unexpected token '4' in expression or statement.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + [math]::max(3 4)
>   +                ~
>   Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
>      ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall

And because strings are tokenized by default in `for /f` loops, the result is `+`.

---

In summary, just escape the comma.

`for /f %%i in ('powershell [math]::max^(3^,4^)') do (set result=%%i)`